# Need help recreating a UA advanced segment in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I am currently trying to recreate an advanced segment from UA into bigquery and running into issues getting the numbers to match.

I need to exclude all sessions from users who have ever completed an event with a category of 'booking' and all sessions from outside the US. My current query gets me close to the number in our looker dashboard but its less than it should be.

This is my current code:

```
WITH Excluded_Users AS ( SELECT visitId AS exclusion_id FROM my_data.ga_sessions_*, UNNEST(hits) AS hits WHERE hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Booking' )

SELECT CONCAT( FORMAT("%04d", EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date))), '-', FORMAT("%02d", EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date))) ) AS year_month,COUNT(DISTINCT IF(totals.visits=1, CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitId AS STRING)), NULL) ) as sessions,

FROM my_data.ga_sessions_* s

LEFT JOIN Excluded_Users e ON s.visitId = e.exclusion_id

WHERE e.exclusion_id IS NULL AND s.totals.visits = 1 AND geoNetwork.Country = 'United States'

GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- `visitId` is just a timestamp of the session (ignoring the midnight split unlike `visitStartTime`)
- I think GA UA uses `fullvisitorid`+`visitstarttime` to calculate sessions
- only cross join `hits` if necessary, save some resources by using subqueries
- you didn't share your segment setup from UA, but let's hope we can resolve it :)

```sql
SELECT 
  CONCAT( FORMAT("%04d", EXTRACT(YEAR FROM PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date))), '-', FORMAT("%02d", EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date))) ) AS year_month,
  COUNT(1) as sessions, 
-- no need to count(distinct fullvisitorid||visitstarttime) since every row is a session
FROM `my_data.ga_sessions_*` s
WHERE 
  NOT exists(select 1 from unnest(hits) where eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Booking')
  AND s.totals.visits = 1 
  AND geoNetwork.Country = 'United States'
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thank you!! now what if I wanted to include other metrics like pageviews and goal completions? I shortened my query for the example but the reason I structured it like that was bc i need to include other custom metrics.

Comment: `sum(totals.pageviews)` should do the first trick. For the goal completions you could open another question ... that depends on the kind of goal.